# sql calculate column value then order by it

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I have the sql below, and I then calculate one of the fields (market_cap) within the application code not the sql. I'd like to calculate it then order the records based on the top 7 calculated from it.

Proposed-ish Sql:

```
SELECT TOP 7 'market_cap' as [market_cap_calc] ??, [tradingcode],[last],[prvclose],[currentsharesonissue]
FROM [PricesCurrent]
ORDER BY tradingcode DESC
```

Asp code for field market_cap:

```
If Not IsNull(rs("last")) Then
    marketcap = 0
    If Not IsNull(rs("currentsharesonissue")) And Cdbl(rs("last")) <> 0 Then marketcap = (CDbl(rs("last")) * CDbl(rs("currentsharesonissue")))/1000000.0
End If

If marketcap = 0 And Not IsNull(rs("prvclose")) Then
    If Not IsNull(rs("currentsharesonissue")) And CDbl(rs("prvclose")) > 0 Then marketcap = (CDbl(rs("prvclose")) * CDbl(rs("currentsharesonissue")))/1000000.0
End If
```

So basically it needs to check if last or prvclose is empty and then multiply either one by currentsharesonissue to get marketcap, and then get the top 7 rows based on that marketcap figure, how do I go about this? make a temporary table first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `coalesce` and a `cte`

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
    coalesce([last],[prvclose],0) * currentsharesonissue as CalculatedColumn
    FROM [PricesCurrent])

select top 7 * from cte order by CalculatedColumn desc
```

`COALESCE()` is going to take the first `NOT NULL` value and multiply it by the `currentsharesonissue` column. Then, we just get the `TOP7` as you stated, in `DESCENDING` order (assumed).

Comment: No sweat at all